# How to show my O365 SSO enabled web application in windows store (O365 app launcher)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, office365, windows-store, azure-ad-graph-api

We have web application built on ruby on rails and added Azure AD SSO feature. We are using OAuth2 and JWT gems for achieving SSO functionality. But after successful user login, our application is not visible on users office portal myapps dashboard. Instead it is only visible if AD admin assigns this app to the user.

But..
Our objective is to show our application on any user(multi-tenant) apps (https://portal.office.com/myapps) once he successfully performs SSO. Like, developing a Web app(ruby-on-rails) that users can install directly from the Office Store.

After our googling we found this ASP.NET DEMO application(https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-WebApp-MultiTenant) which is working same as we expected. After login we are able to see this demo app on users myapps. In the app description following is written "web application that uses Azure AD for sign-in using the OpenID Connect protocol, and then calls a Office 365 API under the signed-in user's identity using tokens obtained via OAuth 2.0. This sample uses the OpenID Connect ASP.Net OWIN middleware and ADAL .Net.".

It is clear that DEMO app uses OpenID Connect protocol, which we are not using. is this creating problem? Kindly guide us in right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found working ruby on rails working example which implements Openid-connect protocol here https://github.com/nov/openid_connect_sample_rp. Then modified db/seeds.db to 
[image: Modified values]

Answer (score 0):

The administrator have to accept the app for the whole Tenant so called admin consent.

http://blog.mastykarz.nl/implementing-admin-consent-multitenant-office-365-applications-implicit-oauth-flow/

https://github.com/waldekmastykarz/sample-azure-adminconsent

hope this help